# React quill drop and paste image module issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill

Maybe someone tried to paste image(or make dnd image) from Microsoft Outlook mails?
It's throw error in console like:
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/asad/AppData/Local/Temp/msohtmlclip1/01/clip_image002.png [(that error )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reQ5g.png)
And quill painted void img icon.[like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10B5c.png)

It's happened cause browser security policy is working, I know, but when I tried to catch paste event handler in my web app - It's working! and I also was able to convert data from clipBoard event to normal format(without file://, like data:C/....).[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78xdb.png)
When I was trying to make debbuger in my custom image handler it's didn't response [my quill modules example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj5vj.png))

Please, can you tell me how we can resolve this options of users event?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hey! were you able to solve this?